# How to authenticate with docusign-esign in nodejs

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am trying to authenticate with docusign-esign, however it is not clear from the documentation how to do it.

The use case is that I do not to do actions on behalf of users, I want to use my service to create envelopes and fetch envelope information.

From the documentation I believe JWT token is the best way to go.

So far I have:

```js
const apiClient = new ApiClient();
apiClient.setOAuthBasePath('https://demo.docusign.net/restapi');
apiClient.setBasePath('account-d.docusign.com');

// integrationKey and privateKey come from https://admindemo.docusign.com/apps-and-keys
const token = await apiClient.requestJWTApplicationToken(integrationKey, ['signature'], Buffer.from(privateKey), 600);
```

The response from the above call is:

```
body: {
    access_token: 'eyJ0eX...',
    token_type: 'Application',
    expires_in: 28800
}
```

Now my understanding is that I should exchange this Application token for an Access (Bearer) token, which I have to use in the Authorization header when making requests to the API. I have noticed that the docusign-esign package has a function `generateAccessToken` but it seems that this is only for the Authorization Code Grant.

Is what I explained before the right way to proceed and how do I get an access token from the Application token above? If not what is the correct way to authenticate my app properly with docusign so I can call `.getEnvelope(accountId, envelopeId)`. Is there also anything else I should do in terms of setup in the DocuSign dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that JWT Authentication fits better for your use case.

You have however requested a JWT Application Token which is only useful for certain endpoints.

You are looking for the requestJWTUserToken() function as that authenticates on behalf of a user. You can find documentation on how to use this function [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdks/node/auth/)

I also noticed you're only requesting the 'signature' scope. For JWT, the 'impersonation' scope is also required as it does impersonate a user to perform actions on their behalf. See documentation for authenticating with JWT [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/)

Comment: Hey @KaranKaushik , thank you for the response. In the first link you have sent it says `The impersonation scope is implied by the JWT Grant operation and does not need to be included` but I will add it anyway
One thing I want to ask further is how should I give consent from that user? Because when I make the call with `const token = await apiClient.requestJWTUserToken(integrationKey, userUuid, ['signature', 'impersonation'], Buffer.from(privateKey), 600);` I get the error `text: '{"error":"consent_required"}',`

Comment: You may be right re: impersonation scope. I don't remember offhand if you need to manually include it. Couldn't hurt!

Comment: Re: consent, follow this guide for individual consent. This is a one time only requirement https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/

Comment: You need the impersonation scope when requesting consent. You don't need it when creating the JWT--there, it's implied.